# p:media plays the video automatically when the page is opened

Tags: primefaces

How to open the page does not play video?thanks everybody.

```html
<p:media value="The video link above the server" player="quicktime">
         <f:param name="autoPlay" value="false"/>
</p:media>
```

Comment: Where did you read the quicktime player supports the auto play param and where did you find it should be `autoPlay` (tried autoplay?) And keep in mind that this is not supported in PrimeFaces 0.7 And does it fail on all browsers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the video is automatically played when I use chrome. safari can not. I just want to turn off autoplay. player = "flash" does not work in every browser. So I use quicktime. So can you give me some advice? Best wishes for you

Comment: So in safari it is **not** autoplayed? Then search the internet. Lots of Q/A about Chrome ignoring this. And honestly... Quicktime is supported in less 'browsers' than flash is... Better to use native mp4...

Comment: safari is not playable, does not support plug-ins.Native mp4 need to cache it?Use StreamedContent?

Comment: Even better... Use google... (for finding the answers)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be resolved, but I struggled with the same problem and found out that native HTML can be used inside xhtml and this resolved my issue.

Hope it helps.

Using escape="false" let you use native html

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{post.htmlVideo}" escape="false"/>
```

and inside backing bean I set value dynamically:

```java
public String getHtmlVideo() {
    htmlVideo = String.format(
    "<video controls><source src=\"%s\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>", mediaURL);
    return htmlVideo;
}
```

Comment: @Kukeltje I think that's also possible, but I wanted to use rendered property.

Comment: Fair enough but then a plain `h:outputText` is still better than a label

Answer (score 0):

The parameter name is wrong it should be

```
 <f:param name="autostart" value="false"/>
```